# Задача про стержни ядерного реактора

Tags: java

Два процесса управляют стержнем катализатора ядерной реакции. Один поток в каждый момент времени помещает стержень на одно деление вглубь реактора, а другой поток вынимает стержень на одно деление в каждый момент времени. Третий поток следит за состоянием реактора, и, если стержень вынут больше, чем на предельное значение, то сообщает об остановке реактора и завершает программу; если стержень опущен в реактор больше, чем это допустимо, сообщает о взрыве реактора и завершает программу. Потоки должны быть синхронизированы.

```
public class NuclearReactor
{
    AtomicInteger level = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int max_level=5;
    int min_level=-5;

boolean stopped=false;
/**
 *  Поток, поднимающий стержень из реактора
 */
Thread heigh=new Thread()
{   public void run()
{ while(!stopped)
{   try
{   sleep(1);
    level.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("уровень повышен до "+level.get());
}
catch(Exception pe)
{
    System.out.println("Error heigh: " + pe);
}
}
}
};
/**
 *  Поток, опускающий стержень в реактор
 */
Thread low=new Thread()
{   public void run()
{ while(!stopped)
{   try
{   sleep(1);
    level.decrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("уровень понижен до "+level.get());
}
catch(Exception pe)
{
    System.out.println("Error low: " + pe);
}
}
}
};

/**
 *  Регулирующий поток
 */
Thread control=new Thread()
{   public void run()
{ while(!stopped)
{   try
{   sleep(1);
    if(level.get() >= max_level)
    {
        System.out.println("Реактор заглох... уровень "+level.get());
        stopped=true;
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(level.get() <= min_level)
    {   
        System.out.println("Реактор взорвался... уровень "+level.get());
        stopped=true;
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
catch(Exception pe)
{
    System.out.println("Error : " + pe);
}
}
}
};

/**
 *
 */
public NuclearReactor()
{
    control.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);  //NORM_PRIORITY MIN_PRIORITY
    low.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    heigh.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);

    control.start();
    heigh.start();
    low.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   System.out.println("������� �������");
    new NuclearReactor();
}
}
```

Не могу понять, почему потоки не синхронизированы. Вроде как использовал для этого атомарную переменную, но вывод все равно не корректный. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Разве взрыв происходит не тогда когда графитовые стержни достают?

Comment: Ключевой момент из задания, который упущен и вообще никак не отражен в решении это - "в каждый момент времени". Т.е. по условию есть некие моменты времени и в каждый такой момент один поток поднимает, второй опускает, а третий проверяет. У вас в программе это моделируется задержкой с помощью `sleep`. Это очень ненадежный способ, в реальности, такая задержка может длиться гораздо дольше и нет гарантии, что один поток не сделает два шага за свой "момент времени".

Comment: @Александр в задаче, видимо, моделируется чернобыльский реактор РМБК, в котором присутствовал концевой эффект графитовых стержней: при глубоком погружении в реактор они ускоряли ядерную реакцию, в рез-те чего происходил взрыв, а вот при их изъятии система наоборот автоматически глушила реактор

Comment: Будем знать:) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас теряется атомарность на этом участке:

```
    if(level.get() <= min_level) // вот тут вы читаете переменную
        {    // вот тут, пока на строке выше идет сравнение,
 любой другой поток делает что угодно с вашей атомарной переменной,
 и в результате может начать выполняться даже другой if,
 где реактор глохнет
            System.out.println("Реактор взорвался... уровень "+level.get()); // и тут состояние переменной не определено
            stopped=true;
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Вам следует использовать lock на этом участке

Да и тут тоже проблема:

```
    {   sleep(1);
        level.incrementAndGet(); //между этой и следующей строкой 
    может произойти что угодно с переменной, только в рамках этой строки  она 
залбокированна и обеспечивается атомарность операции
        System.out.println("уровень повышен до "+ level.get()); // тут состояние переменной не гарантированно
    }
```